# Meaning of ゴリゴリの荒いもの

Tags: translation, meaning, onomatopoeia

Not very clear sense of phrase ゴリゴリの荒いもの
in the sentence

> さてFEDの元となったライカはいかにもドイツ人が作ったきっちりかっちりしたメカで、外見は同じでも細部の仕上げはFEDの方がもったりしていたり使い心地もずっと**ゴリ‌​ゴリの荒いもの**だったりする。

which I could translate as "much more rough in usability", though I'm absolutely not sure.

Comment: Any hint as to in what context you encountered this phrase?

Comment: It's about FED-1, full sentence: さてFEDの元となったライカはいかにもドイツ人が作ったきっちりかっちりしたメカで、外見は同じでも細部の仕上げはFEDの方がもったりしていたり使い心地もずっとゴリゴリの荒いものだったりする。

Answer (score 2):

I would translate it as

> FEDの方がもったりしていたり使い心地もずっとゴリ‌​ゴリの荒いものだったりする
>   the FED has a much rougher feel to it

ゴリゴリ and 荒い are somewhat synonymous and together with もったり convey something like "rough, heavy-duty, clumsy, tough". Note that it doesn't say the camera is actually more sturdy, but that it *feels* like one that is.